# Regular Expressions: How to match when there are at least x a-z,A-Z,0-9,!@#$%^&*()_ characters

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm going through a file with a lot of lines of nonsense, looking for strings and deleting the rest. I've already stripped it of all lines without any a-z,A-Z,0-9, or underscores.

Now I have lines like this:
[image]

I don't want lines like that. How can I choose to select all lines that have at least *x* occurrences of any of these characters: a-z,A-Z,0-9, the underscore, or !@#$%^&*()? It doesn't matter if they are all in order.

Edit:
I want to find lines like this:

```
This is a string.
```

and

```
 _r`[Ġk  oנsDummy[NUL][NUL]ButtonY[NUL]earUpIdlBeDownMonth$@঄9ayH чir /ayTitle@lCenterp@Test
```

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I'm just using Notepad++...regex is universal to an extent, isn't it?

Comment: `regex is universal to an extent` Not really, each flavor has its own quirks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex for ex:

```
^(?=(?:.*?[\w!@#$%^&*()?]){3,}).*$
```

To make sure there are at least 3 of these special characters

Comment: And what about a-z,A-Z,0-9 and _'s?

Comment: @AustinBurk: Check edited code. `\w` represents `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: It's working to a limited extent: It won't select lines like this:
`This is a string`

Comment: It does match `This is a string` **See working demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/w4ehQs7rfg**